# PHP virtual resource access serialization with automatic release

Tags: php, locking

I would like to implement a quick and efficient serialization mechanism between PHP requests for virtual named resources that would unlock when the script is finished, either normally or due to error. I had eaccelerator_lock() and its corresponding eaccelerator_unlock() in the past, but eaccelerator doesn't implement that function anymore. What I want to do is something like:

```
lock_function("my-named-resource");
..
my_might_abort_abruptly_function();
..
unlock_function("my-named-resource");
```

Other PHP scripts calling lock_function() with the exact same parameter should block until this script calls unlock_function() or aborts. The resource name is unknown before the processing (it's a generated string) and can't be constrained to a small set (i.e., the locking mechanism should have good granularity). I would like to avoid try/catch code, because there are circunstances in which catch is not called. Also, any mechanism depending on manual usleep() spinning (instead of native OS blocking) should be avoided.

Mine is the only running application in the server. The system is a CentOS 6 Linux with PHP 5.3.3, Apache 2.2.15 and I have full control over it.

I explored the following alternatives:

- **semaphores**: they are not well implemented in PHP; Linux allows arrays of thousands, while PHP only allocates one per id.
- **flock()**: my resources are virtual, and flock() would only lock whole/real/existing files; I'd need to pre-create thousands of files and choose one to lock with a hash function. The granularity would depend on the number of files.
- **dio_fcntl()**: I could attempt to reproduce the idea of flock() with a single file and fcntl(F_SETLK). This would have the advantage of a good granularity without the need of many files; the file could even be zero bytes long! (F_SETLK can lock beyond the end of the file). Alas! The problem is that nowhere in the documentation says that dio_fcntl() will release resources when the script terminates.
- **database lock**: I could implement some key locking in a database with good key locking granularity, althought this is too database dependent. It would not be so quick either.
- **implement my own PHP extension**: I'd really like to avoid that path.

The thing is, I think someone *somewhere* should have thought of this before me. What would be a good choice? Is there another solution I'm not seeing?

Thanks in advance. Guillermo.

Comment: Firstly, you don't need to precreate files for flock(), you can create them on the fly. Secondly, I don't get how you can use `dio_fcntl()` to lock multiple resources on one file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out dio_open() does release the resources upon script termination. So I ended writing up the following functions:

```
$lockfile = $writable_dir."/serialized.lock";

function serialize_access($name)
{
    $f = serialize_openfile();
    if( !$f ) return false;
    $h = serialize_gethash($name);
    return dio_fcntl($f, F_SETLKW, array("whence"=>SEEK_SET,"start"=>$h, "length"=>1, "type"=>F_WRLCK)) >= 0;
}

function serialize_release($name)
{
    $f = serialize_openfile();
    if( !$f ) return false;
    $h = serialize_gethash($name);
    @dio_fcntl($f, F_SETLK, array("whence"=>SEEK_SET,"start"=>$h, "length"=>1, "type"=>F_UNLCK));
}

function serialize_gethash($name)
{
    // Very good granularity (2^31)
    return crc32($name) & 0x7fffffff;
}

function serialize_openfile()
{
    global $lockfile, $serialize_file;

    if( !isset($serialize_file) )
    {
        $serialize_file = false;

        if( extension_loaded("dio") )
        {
            $serialize_file = @dio_open($lockfile,O_RDWR);
            if( $serialize_file )
            {
                // Do not attempt to create the file with dio_open()
                // because the file permissions get all mangled.

                $prev = umask(0);
                $temp = fopen($lockfile,"a");
                if( $temp )
                {
                    $serialize_file = @dio_open($lockfile,O_RDWR);
                    fclose($temp);
                }
                umask($prev);
            }
        }
    }

    return $serialize_file;
}
```

It seems to work very well.

Answer (score 0):

You can always go old school and [touch](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.touch.php) a file when your script starts and remove it when complete.

You could [register_shutdown_function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php) to remove the file.

The existence or absence of the file would indicate the locked state of the resource.

Comment: Mmm... that would be extremely unreliable. I know it's been used around, but too many things can go wrong with that approach. Determining which process actually generated the lock is very tricky. Also, it would not block automatically when two processes try to access the resource, so it would force me to spin using usleep() waiting for the file to be released; locking order is opportunity based and not first-in-first-served. A little better than that would be using dio_open() with the E_EXCL flag to ensure which process was the real creator of the lock, but it's just a small improvement.

Answer (score 0):

> implement my own PHP extension

You might want to check [ninja-mutex](https://github.com/arvenil/ninja-mutex) library which does exactly what you want